# tracert on windows 7 64 bit always shows just one hop

Tags: windows, networking

What does this mean ? Windows 7 64bit, Russian

```
c:\>tracert google.com

Трассировка маршрута к google.com [74.125.143.113]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

1   224 ms   186 ms   219 ms  la-in-f113.1e100.net [74.125.143.113]

Трассировка завершена.
```

or

```
c:\>tracert facebook.com

Трассировка маршрута к facebook.com [173.252.110.27]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

1   256 ms   248 ms   279 ms  edge-star-ecmp-13-frc1.facebook.com [173.252.110.27]

Трассировка завершена.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have a typical Russian-style ISP that throws Internet standards out the window. So programs that rely on standards compliance like Trace Route return non-sense/jibberish.

Comment: That, or you've got *really* good connectivity.  ;-)

Comment: Tested on another ISP, tracert showed another picture with a few hops. I seems to me the problem is really the provider.